# How to compare an element from ArrayList with a specific String?

Tags: java, arraylist, string-comparison

I am currently working on a quiz game. In the following `public void Run()`, I want to validate the user input `String answer`with the correct answers:
`answersList.forEach(new String`.

I am trying to do this with a `boolean`. But I receive this error message: "Cannot resolve constructor 'String(boolean)'. How do I do to solve this issue?

Initialization of the private volatile boolean:

```
class Broadcaster extends Thread {
private volatile boolean check_point = true;

public boolean getFlag() {
    System.out.println("getFlag is running");
    return this.check_point;

}
```

And after BufferedReader, PrintStrem and so on...

```
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            List<String> answersList = new ArrayList<>();
            try (Stream<String> answersStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(answersFile))) {
                answersList = answersStream
                        .map(String::toLowerCase)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            } catch (IOException a) {
                a.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("The timer isn't working correctly");
            }
            if (answersList.forEach(new String(equals(answer)))) { //ERROR MESSAGE
                write.println("Right Answer");
                points++;
                check_point = true;

            } else {
                write.println("Wrong Answer");
                check_point = false;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Some problem with the validation");
         }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Which strings are you trying to compare?

Comment: the problem is that you're passing  the result of "equals(answer)" which is a boolean value to the constructor of the String hence there is no String constructor which takes a boolean value and even if you were to remove the "equals()" you'd still get an error because the forEach method accepts a Consumer. please specify all the code needed and what you want the end result to be.

Comment: just use List.contains(answer).

Comment: @JosefLundström see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I receive this error message: "Cannot resolve constructor
>   'String(boolean)'. How do I do to solve this issue?

the problem is that you're passing the result of `"equals(answer)"` which is a boolean value to the constructor of the `String` hence there is no `String` constructor which takes a `boolean` value.

---

now to solve the issue you can either use lambda expression like this:

```
if(answersList.stream().anyMatch(str -> str.equals(answer))){
    write.println("Right Answer");
    points++;
    check_point = true;
}else{
    write.println("Wrong Answer");
    check_point = false;    
}
```

or simply:

```
if(answersList.contains(answer)){
    write.println("Right Answer");
    points++;
    check_point = true;
}else{
   write.println("Wrong Answer");
   check_point = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Ousmane for your answer. I did accept this answer because it was according to what I tried to achieve in the first place. Thank you all who wanted to help me...

Comment: @JosefLundström glad to know it helped! :).

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to use

```
answersList.contains(answer)
```

instead of

```
answersList.forEach(new String(equals(answer)))
```

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason String s = new String(false); results in an error, you can't create a string object from a boolean value.

try this...

```
if (answersList.forEach(new String(Boolean.toString(equals(answer)))))
```

I feel like you're making what you're trying to do way more complicated than it has to be though...

Comment: this wouldn't compile because the forEach takes as an argument a Consumer.

Comment: Why are you supplying it with a String then?

Comment: .anyMatch() returns a boolean value. as for the "forEach" a Consumer takes in an argument but doesn't return anything, that's basically what i am getting at.